# How to delete item from Parse Array?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

On my app there is an option to like posts. I use this function which I assigned to the like button with .addTarget to add the user's objectId to an array which is counted to establish how many likes there are. I want to know how I can remove a name from the array, like if someone wants to unlike the post.

```
func like(sender: AnyObject) {

    var buttonPosition: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.table)

    var indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.table.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition)!

    var postsQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")

    postsQuery.whereKey("message", equalTo: messages[indexPath.row])

    postsQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (posts, error) -> Void in
        if let posts = posts {
            for post in posts {
                post.addUniqueObject(PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!, forKey: "likers")
                println(self.likesArray)
                post.saveInBackground()
                self.table.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `addUniqueObject:forKey:` to add to the array you can use `removeObject:forKey:` to remove from the array and then save.

Answer (score 1):

Parse array is really just a JSON dictionary. One way of reordering data is to put an parse array into dictionary , create new dictionary without data that needs to be deleted , and then save new array into parse array.

Comment: How would I do go about doing that exactly?

Comment: Oh wait I figured it out! Thanks for helping me! (: